# How to load test a redis pub/sub channel?

Tags: java, performance, redis, load-testing

I am writing an application which subscribes to a Redis channel and processes messages from the channel as they arrive. I would like to be able to test my application under my expected production load. For my load, I want to simulate 1000 concurrent connections, each sending a message every second - so 1000 messages per second rate.

How can I generate this load? Is there a tool I can use, or do I need to write my own test application which connects to the queue and sends messages? In this case, would I need to do something like:

- create 1000 threads, each of which send 1 message every second to the queue

I would prefer an automated way to generate this load, but I'm not sure if there are any tools for this purpose.

Comment: SO is not a place for asking for recommendations.  I would write your own tools to generate the load in a manner which reflects your application. i.e using the drivers your app will use with realistic message sizes.